# Centering two lines of text next to one line,Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[Quotes(") and 2 lines of text , one coming next to quotes and one more coming below it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf0bU.png)

[Quotes(") and 2 lines of text , both lines coming next to quotes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kP52e.png)

```
  Code used :                               
            <center>
             <div class="badge" style="display:inline-block;width:30px;height:30px;border-radius:50%;font-size:40px;color:#000;text-align:center;background:#fff;padding:5px">&ldquo;</div>
             &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Robert Smith<br>CEO of Geckoos.com
           </center>
```

Using the code i am getting like image 1. Want it to be image 2. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would separate the content into two blocks. Is not recommended to use   to obtain a css separation.

```
<center>
 <div class="badge" style="display:inline-block;width:30px;height:30px;border-radius:50%;font-size:40px;color:#000;text-align:center;background:#fff;padding:5px">&ldquo;</div>
 <div class="textContent" style="display:inline-block;margin-left:5px;text-align:left;">Robert Smith<br>CEO of Geckoos.com</div>
</center>
```

Comment: It worked...But the text is not exactly coming in line with badge its little above.. any attribute to make it correct??

Comment: Thanks... I just changed from display : inline-block to display : inline-table and it worked perfectly